# reserve a row for a specific time using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, locking

I'd like to be able to "reserve" an element similar to how an airplane seat is locked for a short period of time before it's actually paid for. I think the best way is to do it through the database and preferably at the ORM layer.

Here's an example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  bar = Bar.find(1, :lock => true)
  # do my stuff
end
```

I need a more flexible solution though.

Here's how I am imagining it to work conceptually:

```
# action1: 
# put an expiring lock (30s) on an element (don't block unrelated code) 
# other code

# action2 (after payment):
# come back to the locked element to claim ownership of it
```

**UPDATE**: Anyone trying to do this in Rails should try using [built-in optimistic locking](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/a-guide-to-optimistic-locking/) functionality first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional column `locked_until` - but beware of concurrency. I'd probably do that down on the db layer.

Comment: Right, I could use `locked_until` together with `locked_by` to distinguish who did it.

Comment: ActiveRecord does locking/transactions using the database. It's nicer that way, because I can do it right in the code and not worry about different database/SQL implementations (provided they did it right).

Comment: I've done not too dissimilar things in the past and used a locked_by/locked_since column, together with optimistic locking for updates to the 2 locking columns.

Comment: Did you use Rails' built-in `lock_version` for this?

Answer (score 0):

I could have a separate table specifically for this purpose called `potential_owner`. It would have a timestamp, so that one can figure out the timing. Basically it would work something like that:

```
# lock the table
# check latest record to see if the element is available
# add a new record or die
```

This is pretty simple to implement, however locking is not fine-grained. The table describes potential ownership of different elements, and a simple check locks down the whole table. In Tass's solution only the row for a particular element is locked.